# If there are multiple beds, where do I respawn?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play a lot so I know that in minecraft PE if you slept on a bed you respawn there if you die. However, I just created a new world that has about six different beds in it. There are only two beds that are in my house, so how do I know that I will respawn in those? Is it the one you slept in most recently?

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 5):

You are very correct, you respawn in the bed you most recently slept in.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. :)

Comment: If this answer helped you consider accepting it. For more information look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work